# VS2015 - "The key combination (ctrl+K ctrl+M) is bound to command (generate method) which is not currently available"

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, shortcut

Since I upgraded to Visual Studio 2015, I can no longer use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> to generate a method stub (c#). Trying to do so will display

*The key combination<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> is bound to command (generate method) which is not currently available*

Instead I seem to have to use the annoying and clunky actions lightbulb, which requires the mouse or the keyboard right-click key. Is there a way to make the old <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> / <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> work again in VS 2015? Seems odd that the keyboard shortcut is still there but doesn't do anything.

Comment: http://visualstudioshortcuts.com/2015/

Comment: It seems VS2015 removed the `Edit.GenerateMethod` command. The only way (afaik) is to use the Visual Studio SDK and create an addin that adds the command.

Comment: This seems the most reasonable suggestion, I will have a go at this - feel free to post it as the answer :).

Answer (score 2):

you can go to Tools | Options | Environment | Keyboard to customize the shortcuts

Comment: Hmm that is strange.. The key combination doesn't appear in the shortcut list.. maybe its a hangover from the previous version? Its a shame if they removed it altogether :(.

Comment: you can add it your self :)

Comment: I can't see it in the list of possible shortcuts - in VS2013 it was 'Edit.GenerateMethod' but it doesn't exist any more :(